# What are horogram patterns and how do they relate to time signatures?

Tags: terminology, time-signatures

When I was exploring some alternate time signatures, I came across [two references in the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_works_in_unusual_time_signatures) to "horogram patterns". Now, Google thinks this is a spelling error for hologram, and so searching for it doesn't turn up anything interesting.

Does anybody know what a horogram pattern is and how it relates to unusual time signatures?

Comment: see http://anaphoria.com/hrgm.PDF, http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anaphoria.com%2Fhoro2.pdf&ei=Yjg1VLrBCo-yyATdxIGoCA&usg=AFQjCNHgW11o3jcbWh4g3n8c3UQrom1YFA&sig2=Vctb-Gj_GUkuoa5QSswYvg&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw&cad=rja which I found by combining Kraig Grady (the composer associated with them in the wiki article) with horogram in my searches

Comment: http://www.elvenminstrel.com/music/tuning/horagrams/horagram_intro.htm relates horograms to tuning

Comment: @Dave seems to have found the same links I'd have recommended.  Be warned: "Horogram pattern" can send you off to similar mathematical structures applied to optical surfaces!  By the way,  a handy Google tip:  enclose the desired word in quotes and you'll avoid the "autocorrect search term" annoyance.

Answer (score 4):

Papers on Horogram Rhythms can be found at http://anaphoria.com/hrgm.PDF and at http://www.anaphoria.com/horo2.pdf with a discussion of a possibly better algorithm by Viggo Brun at http://anaphoria.com/ViggoRhythm.pdf

You use horograms to algorithmically generate long rhythmic and scalar patterns using the Golden Ratio (Phi).

> Horagrams are diagrams consisting of concentric circles crossed by a
>   set of radial lines.
>   "Horagram" comes from the Latin "hora," hour. Just as you can see what
>   time it is by observing the angle of the "little hand" on a
>   conventional analog clock (or the shadow on a sundial if you are a
>   medievalist), so you can tell what pitch is indicated by the angle of
>   a radial line on a horagram.
>   Source: [5- TO 9-TONE, OCTAVE-REPEATING SCALES: FROM WILSON'S GOLDEN HORAGRAMS OF THE SCALE TREE by David J. Finnamore](http://www.elvenminstrel.com/music/tuning/horagrams/horagram_intro.htm)

The complete explanation of Golden Horograms is far too complex to explain here so I suggest Finnamore's article above, which although it's talking about pitches could also be applied to meters.